# Do we say "durable" for people as in "he is durable"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

We say "*My shoes are durable. I have been wearing them for a long time but they are still good*".

Can we say "*He is durable. He can run for hours without being tired*"?

I did some study and they say we can use "**durable**" for people but it is used for objects more. For people, we should use "**stamina**" or "**endurance**".

Comment: I'd prefer 'sturdy' for a person.

Comment: "He is durable" sounds a bit odd/not idiomatic.  There are some examples of using durable more indirectly, such as: he's a durable player, he's a durable runner.  IMHO, there are better ways to express this: He has great endurance/stamina. His endurance/stamina is impressive. etc, etc.

Comment: He has **endurance** and those **products are durable**.

Comment: Can I swap "the wall of the tower" in the sentence "The wall of the tower is still staunch and strong" for something like that: "Despite his getting on in years he is still staunch and strong"? Would "staunch" come up to describing the peculiarity of the person's bodily condition?

Comment: My personal feeling is similar to Lambie. Things are durable, living things are not.

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/durable) seems to say that you can use it to describe a person, as it gives the following example:

> He has a reputation as the most durable player in baseball history.

However, the meaning of this in the context is given as "*able to do something for a long time without getting tired or being injured*". That's a fairly specific definition which works well in the context of sport. But durability isn't normally a quality ascribed to a person *in general*. When 'durable' is used to describe materials it is often understood to mean something like 'hard-wearing' but actually the word shares etymology with the word *duration* which is of course about time, not strength. Something that *endures* lasts a long time, so that might be because of other qualities like toughness etc, so you see why these things are conflated.

So it only really makes sense said of a person if you say or suggest exactly *what* a person can endure and in what circumstances, as with the example from Cambridge.

When we want to say that a person is strong physically or mentally - able to endure generally under difficult circumstances, we would say they were *resilient*, or *hardy*.

Comment: When used of people, to me it has this strong suggestion of the language of the sports journalist. In normal language there is often something more specific you can use (how are they durable? in what field? why?), but sports writers are always referring to the ability to play a lot of games.

Comment: @StuartF yes, that's pretty much what I've tried to describe. In sport, the quality of *endurance* is often referred to, and it's a similar meaning. I doubt the OP is interested after this length of time but I might edit in something about the etymology linking to duration.